# migrate over clause from mssql to mysql

Tags: sql-server, mysql, migration

How to write the following code into mysql,

```
    SELECT SUM(COUNT(col1)) over (PARTITION by col2) as summation
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY col2
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the code? The windowed aggregate is completely redundant here

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ no this is only a small part of the code,

this is the [full code](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129439/migration-from-microsoft-sql-server-to-mysql-with-clause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact equivalent is:

```
SELECT COUNT(col1) as summation
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY col2
```

The SUM does nothing as there is only one aggregate based row per each partition of the OVER clause therefore it can be simplified to a simple GROUP BY instead.